# Can I change default menu and side-menu of backend with plugins on October?

Tags: plugins, laravel-4, octobercms

How to change the default menu of backend with plugins?

I just found a way to add a menu, but I want to change the settings menu, for example: change the link to another link of `backend preferences`, or simply delete it. i.e.

Can be do it through the plugin? I need any directions. thanks!

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try checking out the code in [Indikator's BackendPlus plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/indikator-backend).

His plugin makes changes and edits to the backend menu quite similar to what you wish to achieve. I'm sure there would be a lot of pointers on going about it in this plugin.